# Kiddush levana- backwards passuk?

Tags: beshalach, kiddush-levanah

In Kiddush levana, ashkenazim say a set of pesukim three times each. One of the pesukim that we say three times is:

> תפל עליהם אימתה ופחד בגדל זרועך ידמו כאבן:‏

Right after this passuk, we say:

> כאבן ידמו זרועך בגדל ופחד אימתה עליהם תפל:‏

Which is the same passuk, just backwards. In the siddur it is listed as the same passuk (sh’mot 15:16). Why is this passuk here thrice, and why is it backwards?

Comment: I know that not necessarily every ashkenazi community says those pesukim, but it’s the best categorization I could think of.

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%207%20Farkas.pdf

Comment: Consider posting that as an answer @DoubleAA

Comment: haven't read it recently. If you do please post it

Comment: He collects several commentators' suggestion and the reason why he doesn't like it, and then goes on to trace back the source to a misinterpretated reading in Maseches Sofrim (his conclusion is that the custom is based on mistake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Shulchan Aruch OC 426.2 in Rema.

> ואומר תפול עליהם וגו' ולמפרע כאבן ידמו כו' ג' פעמים

> They say Tipol Alehem right and reverse three times.

This is an old custom. Abudarham says that despite it is an half verse, he learned from his masters that the atnachta is equivalent to a sof pasuk, so it is allowed to read the half pasuk without the end.

I have found in Sefer of [Moade Hashem](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=55308&st=&pgnum=63&hilite=) an explanation following the Magid Mesharim [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33143&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=) (a book of Kabala written by the Bet Yosef):

> תפול עליהם אימתה ופחד שלש פעמים ישר ושלש פעמים הפוך אומרים אותו בברכת הלבנה הישר מורה על הרחמים וההפוך מורה על הדין כי אנו באים לכלול כנסת ישראל תתאה בשבע ספירות שעליה להכרית כוח המקטרגים הסובבים אותה וכבר ידעת כי **שלש ספירות הם דין** גבורה הוד מלכות **ושלש הם רחמים** חכמה (נראה לי חסד) נצח יסוד ואלו הספירות צריך להרחיק מהם הקליפות אבל תפארת אין צורך כי אין להם עסק סביבו כי הוא בריח התיכון אין שטן ואין פגע רע ועל כן אנו אומרים ששה פעמים פסוק זה להכרית חוח המקטרגם מהשש ספירות הנזכר וכל זה בכנסת ישראל תתאה דאילו בכנסת ישראל עילאה ובספירות שעליה אין שום דבר חיצון יכול לגשת שם כי שם בתי גוואי. ועל ידי ברכת הלבנה אנו מייחדים כנסת ישראל תתאה בספירות עליונות ועיקר יחוד זה הוא במוצאי שבת כי בשבת אין צורך ליחוד זה כי כבר היא מיוחדת בשלמות. .‏

The right lecture illustrates that g-d is merciful and the retrograde lecture illustrates that g-d is punisher. Everyone, the anterograde and the retrograde lecture is read three times because there are three forms of expression for his mercifulness and three forms of expression for his punishment.

I called forms of expression (unweiling) the sefirot that are a kind of manifestation of the Divine will.

We can illustrate this by the translation of the two versions.

Right:

> Shall fall upon them fear and dread by the greatness of your arm they shall be as still as a stone

Here the greatness (chesed) of Hashem is enhanced and will lead to fear from the greatness. Thrice against Chesed, Netsach, Yesod.

Reverse:

> As a stone shall be your arm by greatness and dread, fear shall fall upon them

The strongness, hardness (Gvura) of the arm of Hashem, that is an allusion to punishment, that leads to fear from punishment. Thrice against Gevura, Hod, Malchut

Maggid Mesharim adds that by birkat Halevana we unify kneset Israel who is low and high sefirot. There is a need to make this union after Shabbat because during the day of Shabbat kneset Israel is already unified with them

Comment: Great answer+1! But it doesn’t answer why we say it now...

Comment: Where is the Magid Mesharim you cited??

Comment: Cli k the link @Avi M

Answer (score 1):

[R' Yaakov Reifman](https://yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Reifmann_Yaakov) in Pesher Davar, [pg. 30-31](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37703&pgnum=32), writes:

> "אחר הדברים האלה ראיתי עם לבבי כי הלחשים הנזכרים נוסדו בראשונה לאמר אותם בעת לקוי הירח, אשר הוא סימן רע לישראל לפי דעת חז"ל במכילתא המובאה בילקוט פרשת בא רמ"ז קפ"ח, ובסוכה כ"ט ע"א, ובתניא דב"א ח"ב פ' ט"ז...וכן "תפול עליהם אימתה ופחד וכו'" ר"ל כי האימתה ופחד אשר יש לנו מפני, העת ההיא תפול על אויבינו, ואמירת הפסוק ההוא בהפוך הוא רמז כי יהפוך אלוקים את הוראת העת ההיא לטובה ולברכה, ואמירתו ג"פ בהפוך היא ע"ד שלש הפיכות של הטבת חלום..."

Translate: "After these things, I saw within my heart that these whispered sayings that were mentioned were first set to be said at the time of a lunar eclipse, which is a bad sign for Yisrael according to the view of Chazal in the Mechilta that's brought in yalkut of Parshat Bo, [remez 188](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mekhilta_d%27Rabbi_Yishmael.12.2.1?vhe=Mekhilta_--_Wikisource&lang=bi), and in [Sukkah 29a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.29a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and in [Tannah Devei Eliyahu pt. 2, paragraph 16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tanna_debei_Eliyahu_Zuta%2C_Additions_to_Seder_Eliyahu_Zuta%2C_Pirkei_Derech_Eretz.1?lang=bi)...and also "Terror and dread descend upon them etc" it is to say that the terror and dread that we have from [such an era], that era will befall our enemies, and also the saying of the verse backwards is a hint to Hashem changing the meaning of that era to be good and blessed, and its saying three times backwards is per the three backwards turns of changing a dream to be good.